# Parentheses in java .properties files?

Tags: java, bash, jenkins

I am trying to pass a sql query into a java class via a bash shell script, the script gets the query from an external EnvFile.properties. The query in the properties file looks like:

```
DDAQUERY1=SELECT COUNT(1), marketsectordescription FROM PRODUCT GROUP BY marketsectordescription ORDER BY marketsectordescription
```

The query fails with this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

The value being passed into the script looks like this (as seen in console output window in Jenkins):

```
SELECT 'COUNT(1),' marketsectordescription FROM PRODUCT GROUP BY marketsectordescription ORDER BY marketsectordescription
```

It definitely seems the parentheses are creating some kind of problem as single quotes (') appear near statements with parentheses in them. Is this in fact what is going on? What can be done to remedy the problem?

The env variables are injected into the build with the following Jenkins plug-in:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

EDIT:

It appears it's not the parentheses, it's the spaces. Here's what I'm getting passed in from prop file > bash script args:

ddaquery1=SELECT COUNT, marketsectordescription FROM PRODUCT GROUP BY marketsectordescription ORDER BY marketsectordescription

ddaquery2=select count(distinct(smci)) from issuer

Here's whats getting into the java app:

ddaquery1: SELECT
ddaquery2 : COUNT,

The spaces are delmiting the string and making each word after a whitespace a seperate arg[]. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Can I suggest that your question be edited so that you mention the jenkins plugin you use? As I mentioned in a post, it is probably due to this plugin automatically quoting "words" containing shell metacharacters.

Comment: @fge I am thinking about deleting my answer as its not solving OPs problem, but I am concerned about losing the comments that could be useful for someone for giving correct solution.

Comment: @Smit don't... You may edit it so as to refer to the extended discussion taking place. Unfortunately I don't have the environment to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved the fact the argument being passed in the bash script wasn't quoted, therefore passing every word after a whitespace as a new argument and giving the wrong strings to the query vars in the java app.

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems fine to me. Considering not an typo, the reason its failing because of `,` you have after `COUNT(1)` throwing `SQLSyntaxErrorException`.

```
DDAQUERY1 = SELECT COUNT(1),  marketsectordescription FROM PRODUCT 
                           ^   GROUP BY marketsectordescription 
                               ORDER BY marketsectordescription
```

Comment: the comma isnt the problem, heres the same build minus the comma:

    SELECT 'COUNT(1)' marketsectordescription FROM PRODUCT GROUP BY marketsectordescription ORDER BY marketsectordescription

Comment: I have another query failing that doesnt have a comma either, but does have parenthese: select 'count(distinct(smci))' from issuer

Comment: Wild guess: you use a `ResourceBundle` to read property files?

Comment: no, the property file in injected into a jenkins build where all the variables are made visible to bash scripts called in the build steps

Comment: the bash scripts then pass the query as an argument to the java class

Comment: How is it injected? The `.load()` method of `Properties` does not treat parens in any special way...

Comment: its injected in Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Comment: Could it be a bash issue, then? Maybe the bash script is treating each space-delimited segment as a separate arg (which is what bash does), and quotes them if they need to be. Something else then joins the args using spaces, but that first arg was unintentionally quoted in the interim.

Comment: OK, another guess: this plugin automatically quotes all strings which have a metacharacter potentially interpreted by the shell. Does the same thing happen with, for instance, `*`?

Comment: when I put * in the query it output the names of the aliases of the SVN repo I am using for the build

Comment: @yshavit maybe I guess, but if that was so why dont all the space delimited sections have single quotes? only the section with parentheses does.

Comment: @gjw80 "when I put * in the query it output the names of the aliases of the SVN repo I am using for the build" <-- uhwhat? More details are clearly needed here: how is this file processed etc... This is no "normal" property file handling at all!